# Unable to evaluate form in nrepl + emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure

I have installed the *nrepl*, *clojure-mode* and *starter-kit-lisp* packages. I am able to start the nrepl by opening my .clj file and then M-x nrepl-jack-in.

However when I evaluate any form in my .clj file by C-x C-e, I get the following message:

```
 inferior-lisp-proc: No Lisp subprocess; see variable `inferior-lisp-buffer'
```

How do I get it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this problem a number of times. In all cases, it has been because while *nrepl* has started, the nrepl minor mode has not been enabled in the clj buffer. As a result, any evaluation attempts fail with this error.

There *should* be a "nrepl" menu item. If there isn't, this may be your problem. M-x nrepl-enable-on-existing-buffers should fix it.

I had this problem for a while, and now it appears to have gone away; you might want to try installing clojure-mode and nrepl afresh.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `M-x nrepl-jack-in` worked? If it did, you should be prompted with a repl in emacs, like so:

[image: nrepl jack-in]

nrepl requires leiningen 2, so make sure that you use the right version in your project and that the nrepl plugin is properly installed.

Also make sure that the major mode when editing your .clj file is `clojure-mode`.

You might want to post a screenshot to make it easier to spot the problem.